# Some Items of ViewModel get lost between View and controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post, view, controller

the problem is, that my ViewModel has e.g. 12 items. In the Chrome-Browser i can see (Network--> klick on the postback request --> Headers--> Form Data), that all 12 items have modified values, that i want to save in the controller. But in the controller there are just 9 items that have content arriving. Where are the other three? The Capacity of the Model is 16 but the other items from 9 to 15 are set to null.

How can i find out what happens between the view and controller during the postback?

**Update**

Ok, now i found out that the ModelState doesnt contains all Items, but the Information will be transfered to the controller in the Request --> Form container. Let see, how the missing items will also be transfered to the ModelState...

**ViewModel**

```
 public class ViewModel
{

    public List<tool.Models.Issue> OpenIssue { get; set; }
    public List<tool.Models.Issue> AllIssuesExceptOriginal { get; set; }
    public List<tool.Models.Issue> ClosedIssue { get; set; }
    public tool.Models.Site Site { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit( ViewModels.ViewModel ViewModel)
    {
    //Do something with the content of the ViewModel
    }
```

**View** (a lot more complex)

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.OpenIssue.Count(); i++)
{

@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.OpenIssue[i].Id);
//a lot more HiddenFor fields


Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.Capacity = Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.Count;
var History = Model.OpenIssue[i].Histories.Where(p => p.IssueId == Model.OpenIssue[i].Id).OrderByDescending(a => a.LastUpdate).First();

<tr class="Content_table">        
<td class="Content_Column">
       <div class="Content_all">
       <div class="History">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => History.Description)</div>


           @if( Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.Where(p => p.InternalNotes.Replace("Updated:", "") == Model.OpenIssue[i].Id.ToString()).Count() != null)
           {

               for (int a = 0; a < Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.Where(p => p.InternalNotes.Replace("Updated:", "") == Model.OpenIssue[i].Id.ToString()).Except(Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.Where(l=>l.LastUpdate == DateTime.MinValue)).Count(); a++)
               {
               var OtherIssues = Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.Where(p => p.InternalNotes.Replace("Updated:", "") == Model.OpenIssue[i].Id.ToString()).Except(Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.Where(l=>l.LastUpdate == DateTime.MinValue)).OrderBy(p => p.LastUpdate).ToList();

                   if(OtherIssues[a].Description != "noUpdate")
                   {
                   <div class="updated" style="position:relative" id="@i:@a:Description">
                   <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=> OtherIssues[a].User.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=> OtherIssues[a].User.LastName)</b>  <span style="color:grey;">-@Html.ValueFor(modelitem=> OtherIssues[a].LastUpdate, "{0:dd.MM.yy HH:mm}") </span> <br />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => OtherIssues[a].Description, new { @class = "meeting" }) 

                    <span style="float:right; "><img  src="~/Images/ic_cancel_black_18dp.png" id="Description:@i:@a:@Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.FindIndex(p=>p.Id == OtherIssues[a].Id)" onclick="markActiveLinkDelete(this);">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.AllIssuesExceptOriginal[Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.FindIndex(p=>p.Id == OtherIssues[a].Id)].Description)
                    </span> 

                    </div>
                    }

               }
           }

       <div class="updated" >@Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => modelItem.AllIssuesExceptOriginal[Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.FindLastIndex(p=>p.InternalNotes.Replace("Updated:","") == Model.OpenIssue[i].Id.ToString())].Description, new { @class = "meeting" })</div> 
       @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem=>modelItem.AllIssuesExceptOriginal[Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.FindLastIndex(p=>p.InternalNotes.Replace("Updated:","") == Model.OpenIssue[i].Id.ToString())].InternalNotes)
       </div>


</td>

}

</table>
</div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" name = "Save"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name = "Cancel"/>            
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Show your code. We cannot guess what you have done wrong.

Comment: Which collection property is not binding? If you referring to just `AllIssuesExceptOriginal`, then you code is most likely generating non-consecutive indexers so binding will fail unless you include a input for the Indexer

Comment: Ah, thank you...i didnt thought of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, i added a Hidden field with the indexer for each item of the Model.

**View Updated**

```
@if( Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.Where(p => p.InternalNotes.Replace("Updated:", "") == Model.OpenIssue[i].Id.ToString()).Count() != null)
{

           for (int a = 0; a < Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.Where(p => p.InternalNotes.Replace("Updated:", "") == Model.OpenIssue[i].Id.ToString()).Except(Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.Where(l=>l.LastUpdate == DateTime.MinValue)).Count(); a++)
           {
           var OtherIssues = Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.Where(p => p.InternalNotes.Replace("Updated:", "") == Model.OpenIssue[i].Id.ToString()).Except(Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.Where(l=>l.LastUpdate == DateTime.MinValue)).OrderBy(p => p.LastUpdate).ToList();

               if(OtherIssues[a].Description != "noUpdate")
               {
               //content
               }

           //This is new
           @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.AllIssuesExceptOriginal[Model.AllIssuesExceptOriginal.FindIndex(p=>p.Id == OtherIssues[a].Id)].Id)
           }
}
```